# How is an array sliced?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have some sample code where the array is sliced as follows:

```
A = X(:,2:300)
```

What does this mean about the slice of the array?

Comment: It becomes clearer if you add spaces: `A = X( : , 2:300 )`#

Answer (score 3):

`:` stands for 'all' if used by itself and `2:300` gives an array of integers from 2 to 300 with a spacing of 1 (1 is implicit) in MATLAB. `2:300` is the same as `2:1:300` and you can even use any spacing you wish, for example `2:37:300` (result: `[2 39 76 113 150 187 224 261 298]`) to generate equally spaced numbers.

Your statement says - select every row of the matrix A and columns 2 to 300.  [Suggested reading](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: You might want to add that `XX:YY` goes from `XX` to `YY` in steps of `1`; since you can also use `XX:ZZ:YY`, where you go from `XX` to `YY` in steps of `ZZ`. (i.e. `2:300` goes in steps of one, thus is the same as `2:1:300`, but `2:2:300` goes in steps of 2)